# Go добавляет две записи в таблице MySQL

Tags: mysql, golang

Подключился к MySQL, используя Go, и добавляю запись в таблицу, но вместо одной записи в таблице появляются две с одинаковыми значениями

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/golang")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Connected!")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `age`) VALUES('100', 09)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer insert.Close()
}
```

Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Ты или запускаешь два экземпляра программы, или в базе уже лежат какие-то записи, или что-то ещё. Код выше не может вставить 2 записи.